# Search button on asp.net using C# codes

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working on an activity where my Search button is not displaying my alert message when the user inputs last name that is not found in the database. It is already displaying the record if the last name is found on the database. and I'm planning to put a delete button when the record show. And I don't have any idea how to make it. just asking for a little hint. Thanks.

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBcon"].ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                string Sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE LastName LIKE '" + txtbx_search.Text + "%'";

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Sql, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No record with that last name found!')", true);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Firstly. Does the exception get thrown?

Comment: There is no need to open a connection in this scenario as Data Adapter will open and close the connection for you. Just an observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the allert is included inside the `catch` block which is executed only when their is any error. but in the required scenario you need to check for the existance of data in the recordset from the database; so you need to check for that and throw alert based on that; and you can use the alert in the catch for displaying error message. hence the snippet will be as follows:

```
 try
    {                   
       //Fill the Dataset here
       if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
          {
             GridView1.DataSource = ds;
             GridView1.DataBind();
          }
       else
          {
             ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No record with that last name found!')", true);
          }
    }
catch (Exception )
    {
         ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Error Occured!')", true);
    }
```

Note : You need to to close the connection inside the using block since the using block will take care of that for you. (*Credit : Dhaval Patel*)

Comment: so im gonna put my condition inside the try block?

Comment: @un-lucky: don't you think con.Close() is not require because OP has already used using block ?

Comment: still. the window alert did not pop out when i enter last name that is not found inside database

Comment: @DhavalPatel : Absolutely; valid point - there is no need to close the connection using will handle the connection

Comment: @Alphi: try with this 

public static void Alert(string message,Page page)
{
       ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(),
      "err_msg",
      "alert('" + message + "');",
      true);
}

Comment: thanks for the answers. my program is working now. now im going to do is the delete button. thanks again sir.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check this in `dataset` like

```
if(ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
   GridView1.DataSource = ds;
   GridView1.DataBind();
 } 
else
 {
  ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No record with that last name found!')", true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "<script>alert('No record with that last name found!');</script>", true);
```